# Delete parentheses from a CSV file in Bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, csv, google-ads-api

I'm using a bash script to create a report for AdWords (the AdWords files are in python). I'm generating a "CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" (as CSV file), and one of the measures I take is "conversions".
My problem is this - when I have more then thousand conversions, the number is with " on each side and a comma.
Example:

```
2016-12-25,Campaign_A,Universal App Campaign,264.0
2016-12-25,Campaign_B,Universal App Campaign,"1,535.0"
2016-12-25,Campaign_C,Universal App Campaign,"1,472.0"
2016-12-25,Campaign_D,Universal App Campaign,"1,378.0"
2016-12-25,Campaign_E,Universal App Campaign,382.0
2016-12-25,Campaign_F,Universal App Campaign,431.0
```

When I insert this data into MySQL the cell is divided in 2 and I get "1" in the conversions instead of 1535 (for instance).

So I need your help in one of these two issues:

1. Does anyone know how can I take the "conversions" field as Long and not as Double from the AdWords API?
2. If Not, How can I replace parenthesis (") and commas (,) in several files in the same folder in linux? Since I have a csv file for each AdWords account...

Thank you!

Comment: Paste your expected output for your sample data.

Comment: Maybe you might consider changing the method you use to load the data into mysql rather than changing the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

If you are loading data into MySQL, then you should be using `load data infile`.

This command has an option:  `fields optionally enclosed by`, where you can specify the double quote character.  This will treat commas between the delimiter character as part of the value, not a value separator.

You can review the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it doesn't work... my SQL field is INT, and when I add the "ENCLOSED BY ' " ' ", the SQL see this field as a string (1,535) and the value that get into the table is 1...

Comment: @Bramat . . . I would import it as a string, and do the manipulations in SQL.  You can also use variables and transformations in `load data infile`.

Comment: The tmp table fixed all my problems... Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the file through a sed filter like this:

```
sed -r ':l s/"([0-9]+),/"\1/g; t l; s/"([0-9.]+)"$/\1/g' yourfile > convertedfile
```

It uses a two step approach to get rid of commas and quotes:

1. as long as there is a quote followed by a number ( `[0-9.]+` ) followed by `,` the comma is removed: `:l s/"([0-9]+),/"\1/g; t l;` (this is a "label; remove comma; if something was removed goto label" - construct)
2. remove quotes around numbers (`[0-9.]+`) at the end of a line (`$`)